# How do I find the join size of a mysql query?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I had a query that was resulting in the error:

```
ERROR 1104: The SELECT would examine more rows than MAX_JOIN_SIZE. 
Check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET SQL_MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is ok.
```

I have now changed the query, and I no longer get this error. `max_join_size = 900,000` and `sql_big_selects = 0`. Unfortunately I don't have ssh access, I have to use phpmyadmin.

So my question is, is there any way of determining how many rows a particular query would examine? I would like to see how close a query is to the max_join_size limit.

EDIT: This was the original query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tz_verify` 
LEFT JOIN `tz_sessions` ON `tz_sessions`.`timesheet_id` = `tz_verify`.`timesheet_id`
AND `tz_sessions`.`client_id` = `tz_verify`.`client_id`
LEFT JOIN `tz_clients` ON `tz_sessions`.`client_id` = `tz_clients`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `tz_tutor_comments` ON `tz_sessions`.`timesheet_id` = `tz_tutor_comments`.`timesheet_id`
AND `tz_sessions`.`client_id` = `tz_tutor_comments`.`client_id` 
LEFT JOIN `tz_notes` ON `tz_sessions`.`notes` = `tz_notes`.`id` 
WHERE `tz_verify`.`code` = 'b65f35601c' AND `confirmed` = 0;
```

I can temporarily enable `SQL_BIG_SELECTS` to get the `EXPLAIN` to run - here is the output:

```
id  select_type  table              type    possible_keys  key      ref                    rows  extra
1   SIMPLE       tz_verify          ALL     NULL           NULL     NULL                   93    Using where
1   SIMPLE       tz_sessions        ALL     NULL           NULL     NULL                   559
1   SIMPLE       tz_clients         eq_ref  PRIMARY        PRIMARY  tz_sessions.client_id  1
1   SIMPLE       tz_tutor_comments  ALL     NULL           NULL     NULL                   185
1   SIMPLE       tz_notes           eq_ref  PRIMARY        PRIMARY  tz_sessions.notes      1
```

In rewriting the query, I just split it up to run two separate queries, first to find `client_id` (e.g. 226) and `timesheet_id` (e.g. 75) from `tz_verify`, then used these values in this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tz_sessions` 
LEFT JOIN `tz_clients`
ON `tz_clients`.`id` = 226
LEFT JOIN `tz_tutor_comments` 
ON `tz_tutor_comments`.`timesheet_id` = 75
AND `tz_tutor_comments`.`client_id` = 226
LEFT JOIN `tz_notes` 
ON `tz_sessions`.`notes` = `tz_notes`.`id`
WHERE `tz_sessions`.`client_id` = 226 AND `tz_sessions`.`timesheet_id` = 75;
```

Here is the `EXPLAIN`:

```
id  select_type  table              type    possible_keys  key      ref                    rows  extra
1   SIMPLE       tz_sessions        ALL     NULL           NULL     NULL                   559   Using where
1   SIMPLE       tz_clients         const   PRIMARY        PRIMARY  const                  1
1   SIMPLE       tz_tutor_comments  ALL     NULL           NULL     NULL                   185
1   SIMPLE       tz_notes           eq_ref  PRIMARY        PRIMARY  tz_sessions.notes      1
```

This doesn't seem as neat though as doing it in one go!

Comment: can you wrap it in a COUNT() style query?  it might still throw the error though.

Comment: It is possible your query may be optimized. Can you edit your post with your query and with the execution plan (the output of `EXPLAIN your_query`)?

Comment: @Randy sorry if I'm not understanding this correctly, but would that not just result in the final number of rows being returned? In this particular query, I'm only retrieving a max of around 5 rows. As I mentioned, I have now rewritten the query and it is no longer throwing the error. I would still like to know what the resulting join size is to see how close it is to max_join_size.

Comment: you are correct - i misunderstood the initial question. sorry

Comment: @Jocelyn I have posted the information that you requested. As I mentioned, my 'solution' was to split the query into two separate ones but not having a lot of experience with this sort of thing, I'm not sure if that is the best idea! Thank you.

Comment: I just realized I forgot a word in my previous comment. It should have been: "It is possible your query may **NOT** be optimized". Anyway, now it solved :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the first output of `EXPLAIN` you posted:

- I think the join size is: 93*559*185 = 9 617 595
- your initial query seems to not be always using indexes when joining with tables `tz_sessions` and `tz_tutor_comments`. I suggest adding the following compound indexes (each index is made of 2 fields):

  - table `tz_verify`: (timesheet_id, client_id)
  - table `tz_sessions`: (timesheet_id, client_id)
  - table `tz_tutor_comments`: (timesheet_id, client_id)

If one of these indexes already exist, do not create it again.

Once you added the indexes, run the `EXPLAIN` again (using your initial query). You will notice that the query is now using indexes for each join (look in the column "key"). You may run your initial query again, it should no longer cause the error you had.

## Documentation:

[Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html)
[CREATE INDEX Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html)
[How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html)
[Multiple-Column Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly clear response answering both my original question and showing me how to fix it properly! After following your instructions, the original query was reduced from 9617595 rows to 99 rows. Clearly I need to read up on indexing - I wasn't aware that compound indexes existed. Thanks again.

Comment: I added documentation links to my answer, if you need further reading.